# Create two linked graph in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph, linked-list

Good morning.

I am nwe to Python, I would need to make two "linked" graphs, so that the value in one of them could be selected (in the image the one on the right) and the other would be updated (In the image the one on the left)

The data is a "normal" dataframe with 5 columns, the graph on the right is the first column and depending on where you will select in that graph, update the 2nd graph with the data from the row, updating as the selection is changed.

I don't know how it could be possible in Python or what libraries to use.

Greetings and thank you

Comment: StackOverflow is not a homework solutions service. Please read about how to post questions here.

Comment: If you are new to python this does not seem a task to start working with python. But I agree, this is not a suitable question for this site. You refer to an image, but there is none. You should also provide sample input data (as text), your attempt to do it (in any language), and the problem in that attempt (code). And "Good morning"... you know that we are from all around the world?

Comment: Yes, of course Dennis.

What I am looking for is a developer who has faced having to link two graphs in Python and could tell me which libraries to use or how to do it, and I will thank you if you can help

Comment: tricon

Your comments are not correct. To help you, before answering and assessing if the question is in the correct place, it is better to understand it to give an opinion (than not to decide it would be more) .... and this site is perfect.

I will put screens and I will ask the question in more detail, but without code or data as it is a "general" question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.